# Flickr JSON Parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, flickr

I want to parse the JSON from this url (http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json) but the document actually returns a non valid JSON. See

```
       jsonFlickrFeed({
        "title": "Uploads from everyone",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2012-11-26T18:27:41Z",
        "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": "2012 Thanksgiving Holiday Weekend",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/agape_boarding_school/8220697785/",
            "media": {"m":"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8478/8220697785_bb298ac5b3_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2012-11-24T14:19:21-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/agape_boarding_school/\">Agape Boarding School<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/agape_boarding_school/8220697785/\" title=\"2012 Thanksgiving Holiday Weekend\"><img src=\"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8478/8220697785_bb298ac5b3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"159\" alt=\"2012 Thanksgiving Holiday Weekend\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Great Day at Agape Boarding School<\/p>",
            "published": "2012-11-26T18:27:41Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (Agape Boarding School)",
            "author_id": "36563683@N07",
            "tags": "school boarding agape"
       },  ...
```

I want to let my parser be as general as possible so what is the better way to remove that "jsonFlickrFeed(" part of the document and work only with the JSON it self?

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject> {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url=params[0];

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

}

Comment: this looks like the result of a JSONP call, with &callback=jsonFlickrFeed ...??

Comment: @ScottEvernden, I think you're right. I don't know much about this subject. I just googled it and seems like a JSONP. The thing is I just need the JSON without make my class application dependent.

Answer (score 11):

I have solved this issue by given way.

**Flickr old web API** is: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=xxxxxxxx&lang=en-us&format=json

**Flickr latest web API** is: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=xxxxxxxx&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Use **Latest one web API**.

**Replace** your **user id** instead of **xxxxxxxx**.

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want is th raw json.  You'll want to add a "nojsoncallback=1" to remove the function wrapper.

[See FLICKR JSON Response Format](https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/flickr-json-parsing-noob.html"If you just want the raw JSON, with no function wrapper")

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you will just have to remove this part of the String before you parse it.

If you want to be more general you can search for the first `{` char and delete everything before it, and the last `}` char and delete everything after it. But this still won't ensure that the input is valid.

Comment: That's right, i need to "trim" the document. I was wondering if there is way to do that without modify my parser class. Because if I do so i need to rewrite my JSON parser every time something like that occurs. That's not a good programming practice. As a Python programmer I think regular expression can solve the trim part easily like `".*(\\{.*\\}).*"`.

Comment: You can use regex but it might make your app react slowly when the server response is large.I think the best solution for you will be to return a String from the AsyncTask and parse it differently in each class/project that uses it.