# Parsing JSON data from flickr on android gives 'Value jsonFlickrApi( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject' error

Tags: android, json, parsing, flickr

I'm getting this JSON from Flickr -

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":1,"perpage":100,"total":"6","photo":[{"id":"20337778365","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"cca5a8da86","server":"340","farm":1,"title":"HTML5 1 Color Black","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"20329303232","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"e6e7ab0cdf","server":"317","farm":1,"title":"city lights","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"20329277642","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"0df103ff6a","server":"259","farm":1,"title":"nature_toon","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"20343761221","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"1dcb76f445","server":"3700","farm":4,"title":"Tulips_default","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"20311438736","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"402eb257d4","server":"455","farm":1,"title":"Penguins_def","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"20343768191","owner":"133530693@N05","secret":"f1fca99d27","server":"551","farm":1,"title":"Lighthouse_ault","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
```

I tried to parse it using this on android -

```
//  String jsonData contains the above JSON data.

                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But I get this error -

> Value jsonFlickrApi( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject

What does this mean ? Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out from this answer - [Flickr JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571666/flickr-json-parsing-in-android?rq=1)

that I need to add `&format=json&nojsoncallback=1` in the end of the URL to request the JSON data from Flickr. Now I parse the new one, it has no errors and works fine.

If i dont add this the JSON data starts with *jsonFlickrApi(*